# Javascript/jQuery undefined object length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object that is being created from a database call in the following format:

```
Object { group1={...},  same=null,  group2=null}
```

[image]

I am trying to get the count of items in group1, group2, and same.

I accessed it through the console like so:

```
dataObj.group1.length
```

In the image above, this returns undefined. However, if I have more than one item in `group1`, it returns the count just fine. It appears to only cause issues when there is a single item in the object/array.

Is there a function that can be used to account for these possibilities and return the `length` of items in those objects above?

**Update:**

This is how I am creating my data:

```
success: function(data) {

        // Define our data response
        var d = data.data;

        // Push our data to an object
        dataObj = {
            same: (d.same ? d.same.tools : null),
            group1: (d.group1 ? d.group1.tools : null),
            group2: (d.group2 ? d.group2.tools : null)
        }

        // Render our table
        renderCompare();
    }
```

From here, I am trying to get the amount of items in `same`, `group1`, `group2`.

This is an example of when more than one item is in the response. I am able to access this using `dataObj.group1.length` and it returns `2` which is correct. All I am trying to figure out his how to handle this when there is only `1` result.
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Are you looking for a way to count the number of properties in the object?

Comment: Objects don't have a length, so you should get `undefined` regardless of how many properties group1 has, 1 or otherwise.

Comment: @Archer why would this work when there are two items in group1 then vs a single item?

Comment: Your api is returning inconsistent data. Either fix it at the api end, or you'll have to first test whether or not the group contains an array or an object before you attempt to get the length. Is it null if there are none? who knows, it's inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very unclear.  _Objects do not have a length property._  You told @Tushar in his answer (now deleted) that you should get the length of 1 for group1, yet your image above shows more than 1 property.  You need to explain better, or maybe explain *why* you need this, as this question is unclear.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure that's the case, until he confirms it.  He's been consistent in the structure of the data - `{ group1, group2, same }`.  He needs to elaborate, I'd say.

Comment: @KevinB Look at his edit.  It's anyone's guess now.

Comment: @KevinB - He's creating an object with 3 properties, `group1`, `group2` and `same`.  That's not a conditional array of objects or a single object.  It's an object with properties.  Both the image and his description fit that.  I see absolutely no reason to even suggest that it *may* be an array, so maybe you should confirm that with the OP first.

Comment: Ask the OP instead of guessing and making things up.  What he has posted confirms what I've said, but doesn't even hint at what you've said.

Comment: There is no array, or even a hint of one.  That's an object with properties.

Comment: well, no, he's trying to count the *items* in group1, not the properties. When there is only one *item*, group1 doesn't have a length (it's an object.) When it has more than one *item*, it has a length (it's an array.) When it has no items it is falsey (and his code makes it *null*) it's rather clear.

Comment: @KevinB - I'm sorry.  Truly, I apologise.  I misunderstood his problem and now completely agree with you, after reading it a few more times.  You were right and I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having the question correctly explained to me after my head turned into a block of wood, it's just simply a case of covering eventualities. As @KevinB correctly states, you should really sanitise the response data so it always returns an array of objects, even if there's only 1 object or even no objects in it.  That's what's causing your problem.

If you get this response...

```
{
    group1: { tool: 244, toolName: "blueprint" },
    group2: null,
    same: null
}
```

then `group1` is an object, not an array, so therefore has no `length` property.  If, however, you got this response instead...

```
{
    group1: [{ tool: 244, toolName: "blueprint" }],
    group2: null,
    same: null
}
```

then `group1` would hold exactly the same data, but would be an array and therefore have a `length` property.

What I would suggest is a simple function to evaluate the objects and return the expected response, like this...

```
function getLength(obj) {
    if (obj == null) return 0;
    if (obj.length == undefined) return 1;
    return obj.length;
}
```

In your example, you would use `getLength(dataObj.group1)` and it would return 1.  It would return 0 if it was `null` and return the actual length if it were an array.

Comment: Sorry for being very confusing and vague in my initial question. I was racing against the clock before a meeting and didn't realize I left it so open to guessing. I used the suggested function in your example until I can get around to changing the structure of the response. It worked perfectly and I appreciate your time and well written answer. I will make sure write better questions from the start.

Comment: No worries.  It was my mistake and I couldn't read the question any other way until it finally clicked.  Glad we could be of help :)